# how to change timeline style

Tags: css, timeline

I used this script

http://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/index.html

how to change style from [image]

to this style

[image]

help please

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Its block-elements. Try making them inline :)